# What is the Euclidean polar of the unit ball defined by non-Euclidean norms?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $p\in (1,\infty )$. Denote by $\|\cdot \|_p$, the $\ell ^p$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ one has$$\|x\|_p:=\left (\sum \limits _{i=1}^n|x_n|^p\right )^\frac{1}{p}.$$Assume that $B_p$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by the $\ell ^p$ norm, i.e.$$B_p=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\|x\|_p\leq 1\}.$$My question is, what is polar of $B_p$? The polar of $B_p$ is denoted by $B_p^\circ$, and it is defined by$$B_p^\circ :=\{v\in \mathbb{R}^n:\langle v,x\rangle \leq 1, ~ \forall x\in B_p\}.$$Clearly $B_{2}^{\circ} = B_{2}$, but I am particularly interested in $B_{3}^{\circ}$ and $B_{4}^{\circ}$.

---

**Edit:** Notice that the $\langle v,x\rangle$ represents the usual inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$, not the dual functional in $\ell ^p$.

Comment: It is the ball for the $\ell_q$ norm, where $1/p+1/q=1$.

Comment: Yes it is not straightforward.  It is basically the content of Holder's inequality.  See the section on "counting measure" in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my question. By $\langle v,  x \rangle $; I mean the usual inner product. It has nothing to do with the dual functions of $\ell_p$; that's why the case $p=2$ was clear to me. I will Edit my question. @Ruy

Comment: I guess the answer is still $B_q$, right? @Ruy

Comment: The polar of $B_p$ is indeed the unit ball with respect to the dual function of $\ell_p$, which is $\ell_q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is only an idea

As the comment by @Ruy suggests, it is the set
$$
B^\circ_p= \{v \in \mathbb R^n \ |\ \|v\|_q = 1, \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1\} = B_q
$$
The norm on $(\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot\|_p)$ establishes an isometry onto the dual space which is $(\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot\|_q)$, where $\|\cdot\|_q$ comes from the operator norm. See this explicit map [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317999/find-the-unique-functional-on-ellp-such-that-f-1-and-for-a-given-fi).

So that action of $f = (f_1,\dots,f_n)$ on $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is
$$
f(x) = \sum_j f_jx_j = \langle f,x \rangle
$$
is exactly as that inner product. So if one asks for the all $f \in \mathbb R^n$ such that on $x \in B_p$ we get
$$
\langle f,x \rangle = f(x) \le \sup_{x:\|x\|_p \le 1} f(x) = \|f\|_q = 1
$$
is like asking for all duals with norm 1. The set you want is the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$ with the (operator) norm which is $\|\cdot\|_q$, with $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$.

I think the absolute value in the definition of the operator norm is only required for complex spaces.

Comment: Yes, I agree on your remark on the absolute value. Indeed, let us fix $f\in\mathbb R^n$. We have that $$\sup_{x} \langle f, x\rangle =\sup_{y}\lvert\langle f,y\rangle\rvert.$$ Of course both $x$ and $y$ are taken in the $\ell^p$ unit ball. Proof: Clearly LHS\le RHS. So take a competitor $y$ for RHS. Replace $y=(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ by $(y_1\text{signum}(f_1), \ldots, y_n \text{signum}(f_n))$. This does not change $\lVert y\rVert_{\ell^p}$. Moreover $\lvert\langle y, f\rangle\rvert =\langle y, f\rangle$. So each competitor for RHS has a corresponding competitor for LHS, and we conclude RHS\le LHS

Comment: I'm not an expert in functional analysis yet, but do you agree that the isometry above is also a vector space isomorphism ?, for the case $p=2$ it is clear and famous

Comment: Which isometry? If you give me the explicit expression of it I can think about that. (I think it will turn out to be a linear map iff $p=2$ - I thought about something very similar [several years ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/227213/8157))

Comment: In the link in my answer. BTW I forgot how I constructed it, I'm trying to remeber. So I have to remove that from my answer

Comment: OK. As I suspected it is essentially the same as my old question. These maps are nonlinear, unless $p=2$. A nonlinear map cannot be a vector space isomorphism.